# simple html form to post to two different locations

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I want to be able to post the information in the form to two locations. The form currently posts to one location.

```
<form name="input" action="display.php" method="post">
    search: <input type="text" name="item">
    title: <input type="text" name="title">
    Distance:
    <select type="text" name="distance">
        <option value="5">5 miles</option>
        <option value="10">10 miles</option>
        <option value="15">15 miles</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I've tried

```
<form name="input" action="display.php", "info.php" method="post">
```

hoping it would post to both display.php and info.php but no luck.

Comment: I don't think you can, but a workaround would be to make the target location to send the form data to your second page.

Comment: It is not possible to give two form actions in normal form, If you really need it you can do it using ajax

Comment: cant you just post to `display.php` and then from that page post to `info.php`?

Comment: If your application needs to post the same data to two different php scripts, you should obviously rethink your application structure.

Comment: just merge that parts of display.php and info.php that handle post information

Comment: Why don't you post to `display.php`, write to your database, and read from the database when opening `info.php`?  The user should never look at two pages at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use `ajax` for this. It will help you to send 2 requests to 2 different pages.

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url : "form.php",
           data: {'field1':field1,'field2':field2},
           success: function(msg){
                 // get response here  
               }
           });

$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url : "display.php",
           data: {'field1':field1,'field2':field2},
           success: function(msg){
                 // get response here  
               }
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Snoopy as it won't use cURL. ( You may or may not have it, and this class doesn't require it).
The class can be downloaded at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/
All you'll need to do in include this class and use this code for multiple posts:

```
    $snoopy = new Snoopy;

     $submit_url = "url1.php";

     $submit_vars["foo"] = "bar";
     $submit_vars["key"] = "value";
     $submit_vars["input-name"] = "input-value";
     //making sense on what these are?

     $snoopy->submit($submit_url,$submit_vars);
     //additionaly you can print the results with:
     //print $snoopy->results;

     //then move to the next submit url
     //but, remember!  You must instantiate a new class

     $snoopy2 = new Snoopy;


 $submit_url = "url2.php";

 $submit_vars["foo"] = "bar";
 $submit_vars["key"] = "value";
 $submit_vars["input-name"] = "input-value";

 $snoopy2->submit($submit_url,$submit_vars);
```

Comment: The recommended class is almost 5 years old.